# Tutorialspoint.com: Perl - Formats: Scalar found where operator expected

Tags: perl

According to [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_formats.htm) this should work.

I've tested this in 5.14 (and 5.16) and it seems to work. This does not work in 5.28. However it seems in `perldoc perlform` they're still documented as working.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

format EMPLOYEE =
===================================
@<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< @<< 
$name $age
@#####.##
$salary
===================================
.

select(STDOUT);
$~ = EMPLOYEE;

@n = ("Ali", "Raza", "Jaffer");
@a  = (20,30, 40);
@s = (2000.00, 2500.00, 4000.000);

$i = 0;
foreach (@n) {
   $name = $_;
   $age = $a[$i];
   $salary = $s[$i++];
   write;
}
```

On 5.28, I get

```
Scalar found where operator expected at ./test.pl line 6, near "$name $age"
        (Missing operator before $age?)
syntax error at ./test.pl line 6, near "$name $age"
Execution of ./test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

On which version was this featured modified? Was this a documented change in Perl?

Comment: You're missing a comma - `$name, $age`

Comment: Did you really try it in 5.14 and 5.16? Both say *Use of comma-less variable list is deprecated*. So yeah, the missing comma has been deprecated since 5.12. Add it, and I suspect it'll work with 5.28

Comment: Also I think it should be `$~ = 'EMPLOYEE';`. And of course `use strict; use warnings;` is your friend.

Comment: I recommend [not using this tutorial](http://perl-tutorial.org/rejected/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The removal here was in the comma-less variable list, which triggers a warning a far back as 5.14.

> Use of comma-less variable list is deprecated at  line 6.

Adding a comma makes it work in 5.26,

```
format EMPLOYEE =
===================================
@<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< @<< 
$name, $age
@#####.##
$salary
===================================
.
```